# Why Call() method in JavaScript not pushed in stack?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, memory-management, heap-memory, stack-memory

Can someone tell me that why the `call()` function in javascript not loaded in **stack**?(at least i didn't see it from the Chrome dev tool 's **call stack**).

```
var sData = 'Wisen';

function display() {
    console.log('sData value is %s ', this.sData);
}

display.call();  // sData value is Wisen
```

Step 1. [image]Step 2. [image]Step 3. [image]